# Triggering useEffect only certain conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-effect

I have basic understanding of useEffect. Without second parameter (dependency array) it runs on every render. With empty array, it runs on first render. With parameters in array, it runs whenever some of parameters changes.

Say I have useEffect with two dependencies (from GraphQL query): `result.data` and `result.loading`. I want useEffect to run if `result.data` changes, and `result.loading` is false. Purpose is for example to update Redux store:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (result.loading) return;
  dispatch(updatePhotos([...photos, ...result.data.photos]));
}, [result.data, result.loading]);
```

But there's a catch: I have to include `photos` to list of dependencies. However, `photos` variable will be updated in other place, and it triggers this useEffect again.

**How can I run useEffect only when those two variables changes?**

I can of course use useState to store variable `resultFetched`, set it to `true` in useEffect and then dispatch only if it is `false`. But at some point I have to change it back to `true`, and useEffect runs again, since I can't manually change `result.data` or `result.loading`.

I'm lost how to properly use useEffect in these situations when there is lots of variables to handle.

Currently I'm building infinite scrolling photo list, where list is loaded part by part via GraphQL. But when user opens some photo and eventually returns to photo list, it is restored from Redux to same state and scroll position as it was before opening the photo.

I have spent countless hours trying to get it work, but this useEffect-thing is spoiling my every attempt. :) They always gets triggered before I want them to trigger, because there is so many changing variables.

Also, sometimes I want to run a function within `useEffect` (function added to dependency array), and I use `useCallback` for that function to memoize it. But then I also have to add all variables that function uses to dependency array of that `useCallback`, so function gets regenerated when those variables changes. That means that `useEffect` suddenly runs again, because the function in dependency array changes.

**Is there really no way to use functions/variables in `useEffect`, without them to trigger `useEffect`?**

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how updatePhotos works. If that creates an action then the problem is you are creating the new state in the wrong place. The previous value of photos shouldn’t be used here because as you pointed out, that causes a dependency.

Instead your reducer will have the old value of photos you can use and you simply pass the new request data to your reducer.

Described in more detail here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#decoupling-updates-from-actions

Comment: Yes you're right. That solves the problem with Redux, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have two separate useEffect functions inside the same component and they will work independent one of another. use one for photos and one for data loading. I hope this example helps you to wrap your head around this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [count2, setCount2] = useState(0);
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((c) => c + step);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [step]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount2((c) => c + step);
    }, 1500);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [step]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <h1>{count2}</h1>
      <input value={step} onChange={(e) => setStep(Number(e.target.value))} />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Please refer to this example in sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-6h0oz